# Is it legal to buy/sell a property through power of attorney?

Tags: property, india, indian-constitutional-law

Is there a legal way to buy/sell a property(apartment) in a locality where registration is paused? Heard about power-of-attorney way but not sure if its valid in this scenario!

Any advice on this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A power of attorney (**POA**) is a **legal document** giving one person (the agent or attorney-in-fact) the power to act for another person (the principal). The agent can have the broad legal authority or limited authority to make legal decisions about the principal's property, finances or medical care. The power of attorney is frequently used in the event of a principal's illness or disability, or when the principal can't be present to sign necessary legal documents for financial transactions.

> A person appointed as power of attorney is not necessarily an
>   attorney. The person could just be a trusted family member, friend or
>   acquaintance.

Power of Attorney can have Partial or Full Power depending on the terms satisfied between two parties.

**Example:**

Mr. A made a deal of selling his land to Mr. B and all the formalities were completed except Registry Transfer (all includes contract, money, etc). The registration was not done due to an absence of Specified Government Officer, that time Mr. B has a legal right to create Power of Attorney if Mr. A is satisfied with it.

Mr. A can give Mr. B all powers (Just like registry was transferred) or can give partial power as discussed between the two parties.

**When Full power is given there will be no need of Mr. A at the time of transfer of regisitry in future.**

---

Not a lawyer but one who suffered the same problem two months ago...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chiru. I have one more query. Let's say I buy the property by getting the full power of attorney from owner, is there a possibility of owner cancelling it later(foul play)?

Comment: No, he can't cancel it later as Attorney is done on Stamp Paper with Notary, So there is no chance of cancelling it (foul play). If there will be the previous legal matter with property... I hope understood it better...